# How to revoke session token in keycloak?

Tags: java, keycloak

I need to have only one session per person, for this I wanted to revoke all tokens from active sessions and then delete them

So i tried to revoke the session token through the builtin calling the session.users().revokeConsentForClient builtin session method, but for some reason the token was still valid. So I tried to just remove all sessions session.sessions().removeUserSessions, but that also had no effect.  If there are solutions to this problem?  keycloak version 15.0.2  Code example

```
    public void deleteActiveSessions(RealmModel realmModel, UserAdapter userModel) {
        session.users().revokeConsentForClient(realmModel,userModel.getId(),"master");
        session.sessions().removeUserSessions(realmModel, userModel);
        session.userCache().clear();
    }
```